# Show that this holds in every Boolean Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Prove that this holds in every boolean algebra:
$$ x\land y \land z' =x \space \space \text{iff}\space \space x \lor y =y \space \space and \space \space  x\land z=0 $$
My guess is to start first with the right side:
$$  x\land y \land z' =x \space \space \Rightarrow \space \space x \lor y =y \space \space and \space \space  x\land z=0 $$ 
Now to prove the first argument of "and":
$$ x \lor y = (x \land y)\lor y=y \lor(x \land y)=(y \lor x)\land(y \lor y)=1\land y=y$$
I have skipped some steps, but I guess that is it.

And I don't know how to continue, please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what $z'$ is (with respect to $z$)?

Comment: I think it is the complement of z

Answer (score 0):

In a Boolean algebra, $x\le z'\iff x\wedge z=0$. So the proposition is equivalent to $$x\le y\wedge z' \iff x\le y \textrm{ and }x\le z'$$ which is obvious.

Comment: What about the way I started proving?

Comment: Pleaseeeeeeeeee